# Is Google starting to use Dart? Did they build a Closure (or GWT) to Dart compiler?

Tags: javascript, gwt, dart, google-closure, ecmascript-harmony

We are trying to decide if to use Dart for building a web app. We are looking for a technology that will stay highly relevant roughly for the next 5 years.

Now that EcmaScript 6 specs are around the corner (should be out by the end of 2014) we can't make up our mind if Dart is really here to stay for the long run.

This is because as far as we know there is a missing piece to Google original plan for Dash (now Dart). As Google originally planned in its leaked memo:

> What about the existing code bases for large Google Apps? Won’t they have to rebuild everything to take advantage of Dash? The Dash Cross Compiler should be capable of taking typed Closure code (with some restrictions) and converting to Dash. Although the migration process won’t be fully automatic, it should make moving over to a Dash codebase somewhat easier.

Therefore, this is the reason for this question. 
Is there any effort to date from Google to build a Closure (or GWT) to Dart compiler or translator? In addition, do you know if Google started using it for any existing or new production web app?

In other words, our worry is that Dart will only be a language that is there to fill a transition period and to push Javascript to iterate a bit faster, but as soon as the major browsers will support ES6 (and ES6+) it will be abandoned.

We don't want to start any arguments on the pros and cons of Dart, we just need some factual info that could help us in this key decision.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that anyone can guarantee you anything. But if Dart VM will become a part of Chrome(consumer version) then it will be something. Dart might end up as primary server side language but before starting any huge project i would wait before it's VM becomes part of the Google App Engine.  For small projects it's absolutely ready and dart2js has really good performance, sometimes even better than handwritten JS + it provides tree shaking.

Comment: yes, I know the merits of Dart and I think it would be ready for our project. I am worried only because it seems that Google is still not using it internally.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/community/who-uses-dart.html

Comment: @JAre thanks, yes you could add that link as an answer. It would confirm that Google has made no effort to start using Dart in any external web app. If there are no other better answer in the coming weeks I would accept yours.

Comment: @JAre dartlang.org/community/who-uses-dart.html. Google uses Dart only in Google Fiber website?

Comment: i think Dart discussion group is better place for this kind of questions. Also you might try contacting @SethLadd.

Comment: np. I think the main question is "where will you find more hands down the road" because will dart progress or not - doesn't change much. Even with Dart's in it's current form you can make real world projects. BUT! It much easier to find decent JS developer in your region if you need extra "brain power" for rapidly growing project then the dart ones. But i totally agree with GünterZöchbauer it's a great language and it can save you a ton of time and make you happy. If you create post in the groups - please, give us the link

Comment: Google uses Dart for internal and external applications. Adwords Front End is starting to migrate to Dart, among others.

Comment: @SethLadd thanks a lot for the info. Together with the dartlang thread that I opened: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/v6wsIW96QcA
I have got all the feedback I needed to be able to bet on the future of Dart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I have been mostly developing with `GWT` (scientific web-apps) but recently I also started to work with `Dart`.

Google is heavily invested in `Dart` (look at all the I/O talks) so I can't really imagine them dropping it. Also ES6 will solve some problems (modules, classes, etc) but it still is `Javascript` with all its problems and drawbacks.

While working with `GWT` there were two aspects, which make developing large scale web-apps actually feasible:

- structured language (Java) & static types
- compiler

1.) Java is a statically typed language and thus allows you to easily catch errors during development. Furthermore it is much easier to refactor your code when your IDE understands the structure of your code. The same advantages also apply to `Dart`.

2.) Both the `GWT` compiler as well as the `Dart` compiler are quite sophisticated They can do `global optimizations` (https://plus.google.com/111739836936169749229/posts/DSUgfWefyR3) and `tree shaking` (https://plus.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts/VK8URgZiLbS). If you develop web-apps with a 100.000 LOC, this is quite important and crucial.

`Dart` has one big advantage over `GWT` concerning the development story: `Dartium` has the `DartVM` baked in. This makes development and iterations as convenient as with `Javascript`
(`GWT` has `SuperDevMode` but that's not as fast).

You can checkout [Java2Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/tree/master/dart/editor/util/plugins/com.google.dart.java2dart) which could be used to transpile `GWT` code to `Dart`

Comment: I think GWT had more air time in it's days, but it might be due to general shift in Google IO from developers to marketing and PR.

Comment: The reason why GWT was not featured at I/O is that it is not owned by google anymore and has its own developer conference (GWT.create)

Comment: I'm talking about how Google looked to be really committed to GWT in compression to Dart from the Google IO representation stand point. When GWT entered the scene Google gave it a large chunk of IO air time, but, nonetheless, they withdraw resources from the project  and i can't see such commitment for Dart even at this stage. I think they are playing really safe now. Also GWT had really good adoption (Sencha, Smart GWT, Vaadin etc) But I'm optimistic in general.

Comment: ES6 introduces features that can't be polyfilled/shimmed so it's quite a leap of faith to rely on it before, say, 2018. I'm saying here ES6 does not shadow Dart's advantages since Dart is == ES6 now + jQuery + modernizer + .... + IDE + debugger + faster VM (now on Android phones !!). And an ECMA standard since 04/july/14 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of a Closure to Dart converter. I think this is obsolete because Dart can just make use of JavaScript by Dart-js-Interop. This helps to migrate existing apps to Dart by migrating the code part for part.

You can ask as many questions as you want, you won't get a guarantee that Dart will stay but I love to work with Dart and what I have heard many others do as well. I think this shows that Google created a great product. It will stay if enough developers jump on the bandwagon.